# Monitoring CPU freq in real time

Tags: monitoring, amd-processor, frequency, cpupower

I have 16.04 LTS installed on a Ryzen 1700X computer. I am able to see the frequency of each of the individual 16 threads by running the command `sudo cpupower monitor`. Along with the frequencies, it displays information regarding power states, and what looks like the CPU base frequency.
This is an example of what is displayed:

```
|Mperf               
CPU | C0   | Cx   | Freq 
   0|  0.09| 99.91|  3493
   1|  0.04| 99.96|  3495
   2|  0.06| 99.94|  3498
   3|  0.06| 99.94|  3495
   4|  0.16| 99.84|  3439
   5|  0.05| 99.95|  3497
   6|  0.09| 99.91|  3494
   7|  0.10| 99.90|  3500
   8|  2.89| 97.11|  3474
   9|  0.13| 99.87|  3496
  10|  0.56| 99.44|  3485
  11|  0.07| 99.93|  3495
  12|  2.22| 97.78|  3474
  13|  0.19| 99.81|  3497
  14|  1.51| 98.49|  3490
  15|  0.01| 99.99|  3445
```

I have 2 requests. The first is how can I monitor these numbers in semi-real time; for a counter to show a frequency and update every 1 second? Is there a convenient feature in Bash which could repeat the command in a frequent manner?

The other concern is to strip the middle 2 columns or even better the first 3 and just leave the "Freq" column. This way I can easily input the data into Libreoffice Calc and compute averages and sums.

A possible alternative would be to setup psensor to be able to read the frequencies in real time. I am able to get psensor to display temperature and CPU usage via a modprobe command, however it does not show the fluctuation of frequencies (something I am interested in for overclocking and fine tuning purposes).

Comment: If i could generate a simple X window which would update the frequency automatically using this command, that would already be of huge help

Answer (score 2):

My favorite tool is **Conky** which I part to the right side of one of my monitors:

[image: CPU Powersave.gif]

My code only has 8 CPU's and you would have to modify it for 16 CPUs:

```
#------------+
# i7-6700 CPU|
#------------+
${color2}${voffset 5}Intel® i-7 6700HQ 3.5 GHz: ${color1}@  ${color green}${freq} MHz
${color}${goto 13}CPU 0 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu1}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu1 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 1 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu2}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu2 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 2 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu3}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu3 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 3 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu4}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu4 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 4 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu5}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu5 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 5 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu6}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu6 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 6 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu7}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu7 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 7 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu8}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu8 18}
${color1}All CPU ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${hwmon 1 temp 1}°C ${goto 250}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
${color green}$running_processes ${color1}running of ${color green}$processes ${color1}loaded processes.
${color}Load Avg. 1-5-15 minutes: ${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $1}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4} ${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $2}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4} ${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $3}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4}
```

You can literally find thousands of examples and solutions on [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865) for Conky.